# Save Rocket.Chat configuration in files to deploy it easily

Tags: rocket.chat

I have just installed a new instance of Rocket.Chat (on heroku), and I'm beginning to play with the configuration. I changed the colors, added some Incoming and Outgoing Integration Scripts and changed some other parameters here and there.

Is it possible to get those changes in a configuration file so that if I have to redeploy another Rocket.Chat instance elsewhere I could apply this configuration easily ?

Answer (score 1):

I will share my experience feedback.

I installed Rocket.Chat in **manual** (step by step)

In a concern of reinstalling my VPS, I recovered all the data of the database mongoDB in **.gz** file format and was able to restore without encumber with the following commands :

```
#for dump
mongodump --archive=rocketchat.gz --gzip

# for restore
mongorestore --gzip --archive=rocketchat.gz
```

[MongoDB's dump doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump) - [MongoDB's restore doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/)

Good luck